# asp.net mvc - how to pass more than 1 default paramters when mapping routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass more that 1 default parameters when mapping a route i.e

```
routes.MapRoute(
            null, 
            "items", 
            new { controller = "Items", action = "Index",  new { page = 1, pageSize=10 } } //prob here
        );
```

Works fine with 1 parameter like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            null, 
            "items", 
            new { controller = "Items", action = "Index",  page = 1 } //prob here
        );
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already declaring **three** default parameters here:

```
new { controller = "Items", action = "Index",  page = 1 }
```

Adding a fourth is as simple as:

```
new { controller = "Items", action = "Index",  page = 1, pageSize=10 }
```